# Divide two strings to form palindrome

Tags: algorithms, strings

Given two strings, A and B, of the same length $n$, find whether it is possible to cut both strings at a common point such that the first part of A and the second part of B form a palindrome.

I've tried bruteforce, and this can be achieved in $O(n^2)$. I'm looking for any kind of optimization that is faster than $O(n^2)$. I'm not familiar with backtracking and DP. So, can anyone throw some light?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you think of *any* algorithm at all?

Comment: I do not see a thoughtful **question** here. Did you mean to ask whether there is an algorithm with $o(n^2)$ running time? If so, please make it explicit.

Comment: The brute-force method would take $ O(n^2) $ time. Do you need a solution with lesser complexity?

Comment: @SiluPanda It looks like you missed the little $o$ in my comment. $o(n^2)\not=O(n^2)$.

Comment: It will not be too surprising if there is a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've tried bruteforce, and this can be achieved in O(N^2). I'm looking for any kind of optimization. I'm not familiar with back tracking and DP. So, can anyone throw some light....whether i should thing in these lines?

Comment: I'd start by counting how many characters from the start of a and from the end of b are matching, and I think from that you can deduce the solution (if one exists). Say 100 characters. If 79 match you cut at 50. If 5 match (but not 6) you can't cut at a position > 5 and < 95.

Comment: @rplusg Even when a question is not homework, we like to see an actual question here. All you have given in the question body is the description of an algorithmic problem. Please [edit] your answer to clarify what your actual question is and what sort of solutions you have tried so far, why this is not sufficient for you, and what sort of solution you'd want.

Comment: @rplusg I would have posted the exactly same content on many other sites as you had initially. However, this site is mildly different in that more emphasis is put on the quality of the question. All you needed to do to make the question acceptable is to include one of your comments in the question; it happens that comments on this sites does not count much towards the quality of the question since comments are secondary in reading, searching, etc. I just did inclusion for you. If you have not yet, please read [how to ask a good question](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284).

Comment: I will just leave this here, looks like some people has to read this daily. 

https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Some notations in Python convention***

- $S[:i]$ means the first $i$ letter of string $S$.
- $S[-i:]$ means the last $i$ letter of string $S$. ($S[-0:]$ is the empty string, which is not Python convention.)
- $S+T$ means the concatenation of $S$ and $T$.

#### The problem in clearer terms

Given two strings, $A$ and $B$, of equal length $n$, find whether $A[:i]+ B[-(n-i):]$ is a palindrome for some $i$.

#### Brute force

For each $i$ in $0, 1, \cdots, n$, we can check if $A[:i]+ B[-(n-i):]$ is a palindrome. This search by brute force runs in $O(n^2)$. Its average time-complexity is $O(n)$ under some reasonable assumptions. It is very easy to implement.

#### Algorithm in $O(n)$

Let us take a closer look what happens when we get a palindrome. For example, 
$$\begin{aligned}
A&=ab12321xy\\
B&=\text{**}5\text{***}4ba\\
C=A[\text{:}7]+B[-2\text{:}]&=ab12321ba\quad \text{which is a palindrome.}
\end{aligned}$$

Note that 12321 in $C$ is a palindrome that sits in the middle of $C$, which is not surprising since the central part of a palindrome is also a palindrome. Since the lengths of $A$ and $B$ are the same, that 12321 should sit in the middle of $A$ as well.

Note the remaining part after $12321$ has been removed, $abba$ is also a palindrome.

The above indicates the following simple algorithm.

1. Compare the letters at the front of $A$ with the corresponding letters at the behind of $B$ one by one so as to find $i_0$, the largest $i\le n/2$ such that $A[:i]+B[-i:]$ is a palindrome.
2. Starting from the center of $A$, expand both ways to find the longest palindrome sitting in the central of $A$. Let $c_A$ be its length. If $2i_0 + c_A\ge n$, return yes.
3. Starting from the center of $B$, expand both ways to find the longest palindrome sitting in the central of $B$. Let $c_B$ be its length. If $2i_0 + c_B\ge n$, return yes.
4. If we have reached here, return no.

#### Exercise

Given two strings, $A$ and $B$, devise an $O(n)$ algorithm that determines whether $A[:i]+ B[-(n-i):]$ is a palindrome for some $i$, $0\le i \le\text{len}(A)$ and $0\le n-i \le\text{len}(B)$.
(This exercise should be easy if you know Manacher's algorithm.)

Comment: "The central part of a palindrome is also a palindrome" should be "Any central part of a palindrome is also a palindrome"

Comment: In step 2, we can just check whether the central part of $A$ of length $n-2i_0$ is a palindrome or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by cutting at a common point you mean that only one cut can be made at the same index in both Strings and the resulting string must be of the same length as the original length of Strings A and B, and that A *must* be the first string and B *must* be the second?

In this case, this algorithm should run in o(n) time. Start from the first character in A and the last character in B and count the number of matching characters until you find a mismatch (If you reach the center of the strings then you have found a palindrome by simply putting together each half of String A and String B).

Now you know that if you cut at either right before the first mismatched character in String A or right after the first mismatched character in B, that each half on the ends of the String formed will match, and therefore if the characters in between form a palindrome, then the whole string will form a palindrome. Therefore you can simply check if either String A or String B, minus the first and last n characters, where n is the number of characters that matched in your initial check, is palindromic. If the answer is no, then a palindrome cannot be formed.

Example:

- String A: ABCORLUXIENSTU
- String B: QLDWXYZZYXWCBA

Up the line, you would compare A to A, then B to B, then C to C, then N to W, finding a mismatch. You would then check each String to see if the internal string without the first and last three characters is palindromic. ORLUXIEN in the first string is not, but WXYZZYXW in the second string is, therefore you can form the palindrome ABCWXYZZYWXCBA by cutting at index 3.

I'm pretty certain this will always find a palindrome if there is one, if there are any cases I'm missing, please let me know.